# Error after installing R 3.0.1

Tags: r

We have 2 servers running R.

One server has 2.15.2. Here is the program runs fine.

We installed latest R on another server - version 3.0.1.

On this server, we are getting the following error with the same code

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  5 nodes produced errors; first error: incorrect number of dimensions
Calls: build.model ... clusterApply -> staticClusterApply -> checkForRemoteErrors
Execution halted
```

Looks like 2.15.2 does not use snow, while 3.0.1 uses snow for parallel computation.

How can I fix this problem?

The error may be coming from Rscript. We are not sure. Here is the code

```
model.building.main <- function(configFile, model.repository) {

  source("read_QE_config.R")
  param <- read.QE.config(configFile)
  model.count <- 0

  for (i in 1:nrow(param$models)) {

    model.name <- param$models$model.name[i]
    independent.variables <- param$independent.variables[param$independent.variables$model==model.name &
                                                           param$independent.variables$in.model,]

    stage.number <- as.integer(param$models$stage.number[i])
    stage.numbers <- as.integer(independent.variables$stage.number)
    relevant.variables <- independent.variables[stage.numbers <= stage.number,]

    if (!all(!relevant.variables$incomplete.data)) {

#       model.file.name <- paste(model.repository, "/", model.name, "_", stage.number, "_existing.Rdata", sep="")  
      exec.command <- paste("Rscript script_model_building.R", configFile, model.name, stage.number, "existing", model.repository, sep=" ")
      cat(paste(exec.command, "\n", sep=" "))
      system(exec.command, wait=FALSE)
      model.count <- model.count + 1

#       model.file.name <- paste(model.repository, "/", model.name, "_", stage.number, "_new.Rdata", sep="")
      exec.command <- paste("Rscript script_model_building.R", configFile, model.name, stage.number, "new", model.repository, sep=" ")
      cat(paste(exec.command, "\n", sep=" "))
      system(exec.command, wait=FALSE)
      model.count <- model.count + 1

    } else {

#       model.file.name <- paste(model.repository, "/", model.name, "_", stage.number, "_existing.Rdata", sep="")
      exec.command <- paste("Rscript script_model_building.R", configFile, model.name, stage.number, "existing", model.repository, sep=" ")
      cat(paste(exec.command, "\n", sep=" "))
      system(exec.command, wait=FALSE)
      model.count <- model.count + 1

    }

  }  

  return(model.count)


}
```

Error is coming in the following line in another file

```
gbm.model.standard <- gbm(Y ~ .,
                                distribution         = param$distribution,
                                data                 = data.standard,
                                n.trees              = gbm.training.ntrees,
                                interaction.depth    = 3,
                                shrinkage            = 0.001,
                                bag.fraction         = 0.6,
                                verbose              = param$gbm.detail,
                                cv.folds             = cv.folds.standard)
```

We were using gbm_1.6-3.2 in R 2.15.2 and gbm 2.1 in R 3.0.1

Comment: Can you provide the code that's producing the error?

Comment: posted code producing the error

Comment: Have you tried useing `browser` in the code to isolate the location of the error?

Comment: R 3.0 makes some changes to the way internal .call() s are handled as well as long integers. As these are major changes I wouldn't advise running out of version between a master and nodes. Also have you checked your package versions? It's possible the 3.0.1 has newer versions installed.

Comment: Are you deploying these from the servers themselves? or are you deploying from your local machine? If the latter, what is the sessionInfo() on the local machine?

Comment: We reverted to gbm_1.6 for now.